# Temporary domain for new version of a website

Tags: seo, domains, subdomain, multiple-domains, redesign

I'm redesigning a website. Many parts of the old (current) website are still useable, but some other critical parts (say product page & purchase flow) are broken and the new, redesigned website should be live asap (even incomplete).

What I'm currently doing is having 2 websites:

```
example.com  /* old website,        main domain    */
example.net  /* redesigned website, similar domain */
```

And in future, I will remove the old website:

```
example.com  /* redesigned website, main domain */
example.net  /* redirect, forward or make alias to example.com */
```

The biggest problem here is SEO. I'm not sure what is the best strategy for this situation so we don't lose rankings. As I said, `example.net` will be only available until the redesign process is done. After that, old website files on `example.com` will be removed and new website files will be moved from `example.net` to `example.com`.

How can I keep `example.net` rankings after the redesign is done and I migrate it to `example.com`?
How can I keep the previous website's rankings while replacing it with the new one?

(And one more thing; is it better to use `example.net` or `new.example.com` as the temp domain? Does it affect domain authority or something?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I keep example.net rankings after the redesign is done and I migrate it to example.com?

Implement a 301 redirect (permanent redirect) from example.net to example.com. But why does example.net have rankings? Wasn't it just your staging environment? It should have zero notable rankings.

> How can I keep the previous website's rankings while replacing it with the new one?
> With a redesign, there is no guarantee to keep your rankings. Especially not if critical parts are now broken.

Did the URL structure change? If yes, please redirect the old URLs on example.com to the soon to be new URLs on example.com

> is it better to use example.net or new.example.com as the temp domain?

It does not matter. Best practice is actually not to allow Google to crawl your staging environment (temp domain). There are no benefits but all kinds of problems with that.

> Does it affect domain authority or something?

Zero. The only thing that might happen is that you confuse Google and lose rankings by having both the current and the new version of your website online. That is why the best practice is to block Goolge bot from crawling your new site on the temp domain.